# Python how to get parameters from bat file

Tags: python, batch-file

I have requirement to copy files from source to destination in python file.
used

```
distutils.dir_util.copy_tree(src_dir,dest1_dir); 
distutils.dir_util.copy_tree(src_dir,dest2_dir);
```

`src_dir`, `dest1_dir` and `dest2_dir` are hard coded in the python file as

```
src_dir =/xx/ttt/yyy
dest1_dir=/xx/yyy/uuuu
```

But don't want hard code. I am calling this python script from abc.bat file

how to pass `src_dir`, `dest1_dir`, `dest2_dir` to python script from bat file and in python script how to get the passed parameters from the bat script. 
so that I replace the src and destination directory in the copy tree.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do something fast @AdamSmith's approach will be great.

On the other hand, if your program will grow a lot on options or you want to create more elegant parameters such as:

**your_script --src-dir=*src_dir* --dest-dir=*dest_dir***

you can use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) which will do the job great.

Even more, if you want to print something like this:

```
$ python copier.py -h
usage: copier.py [-h] [--src-dir] [--dest-dir] 

Copies a directory from source to destination

positional arguments:
--src-dir The source directory
--dest-dir The destination directory

optional arguments:
 -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the whole argument values list with

```
import sys

sys.argv
```

the first element is always the name of the file, so you're looking at `sys.argv[1:]`

```
src, dst = sys.argv[1:]
```

But is there some reason that you're using the `distutils` module for this? It's more often called from `shutil`

```
import shutil
import sys

src, dst = sys.argv[1:]
try:
    shutil.copytree(src, dst)
    # shutil.copytree(src, dst2)  # how are you generating dst2?
except Exception:
    # something went wrong. Unless there's a reasonable way to recover we should just
    raise
```